# Distribution with a random argument

Tags: probability-theory

Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, how can I reformulate

\begin{align}
P(X>Y)
\end{align}
into something I can calculate?

From my lecture notes I have (without proof) that

\begin{align}
P(X>Y) &= \int_0^\infty P(X>y)\, \mathrm dF_Y(y)
\\&=
E_Y[\bar F_X(Y)].
\end{align}
In the case of for example $X$ and $Y$ being Gaussian or log-normally distributed, neither have a closed form distribution function and hence I do not see how I can procede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are independently normal distributed, then $X-Y$ is normally distributed as well and $P(X>Y)=P(X-Y>0)$ can be expressed in terms of the error function.

Say, $X$ is $N(a,\sigma_X^2)$ distributed and $Y$ is $N(b,\sigma_Y^2)$ distributed, then $X-Y$ is $N(a-b,\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)$ distributed and we can compute \begin{align}P(X<Y)&=P(X-Y<0)=P(X-Y-(a-b)<b-a)\\&=P\left(\frac{X-Y-(a-b)}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}}<\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}}\right)=\text{Erf}\left(\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}}\right).\end{align}

Comment: I suppose this can be done also for the log-normal distribution then by using $P(X>Y)=P(\log X>\log Y)$ and using the same arguments as above then?

What about the more general case?

Comment: Yes. It would, however, be much more difficult to answer the question if $X$ is normal and $Y$ is log-normal distributed. See for example, 'The convolution of the normal and lognormal distributions', D. M. Hawkins, 
South African Statistical Journal, Vol. 25, No. 2. (1991), pp. 99-128.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your lecture notes are incorrect (or you transcribed what is written there incorrectly when you asked the question here).  The correct expression (for
continuous random variables) is
$$P\{X > Y\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X > y\mid Y = y\}f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy$$
(note lower limit) and is an expression of the law of *total probability.*
For *independent* random variables, $P\{X > y\mid Y = y\} = P\{X > y\}$ and
so what your lecture notes *should* be saying is
$$P\{X > Y\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X > y\}f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X > y\}\,\mathrm dF_Y(y)$$
(once again, note lower limit).

If $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* normal, then $X-Y$ is a normal random variable
with mean
$\mu_X+\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2-2\rho \sigma_X\sigma_Y$, 
and so $P\{X > Y\} = P\{X-Y>0\}$ can be expressed in terms of the cumulative
standard Gaussian CDF $\Phi(\cdot)$ or the erf function as in whz's answer.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the lecture notes implicitly assume positive random variables since the topic is claim sizes and deductibles in a non-life insurance context.

Comment: But discussing _normal_ random variables that have range $(-\infty,\infty)$, and then giving a formula that applies only to positive random variables, seems not very sensible; the savings in toner from replacing $-\infty$ by $0$ hardly seem worth it!